# InputException Occuring in GetStream.io when tring to Add Reactions for an activity form NodeJS

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

When I try to add reaction to an activity, it shows an error message that user_id cannot be empty. As per the doc, there where no field to pass the user id in JS/NODE sample code. please help.

Language: Node JS

Code Used :

```
await client.reactions.add("like", activity.id );
```

also tried

```
await client.reactions.add("like", activity.id, "jack" );
```

Response: **Error**

Details : `'{"detail":"Errors for fields \'user_id\'","status_code":400,"code":4,"exception":"InputException","exception_fields":{"user_id":["user_id is a required field"]},"duration":"0.16ms"} with HTTP status code 400' }`

Comment: are you calling client.setUser before using the reaction endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client is a serverside client(initialized with api key and api secret), you need to specify the user_id in the call to `reactions.add`. If you use a clientside integration(initialized with api key, user token and app_id), the user_id doesn't need to be specified.

For serverisde your code will be:

```
const userId = 'bob';
await client.reactions.add('like', activity.id, null, { userId });
```

For clientside you will have:

```
const token = srvClient.createUserToken('bob'); //srvClient is initialized with apiKey and apiSecret
const client = stream.connect(
    apiKey,
    token,
    appId,
);
await client.reactions.add('like', activity.id);
```